# Is it possible to prove the inconsistency of an axiomatic system?

Tags: axioms

As I understand it, it is possible to prove the *consistency* of a given axiomatic system using a *stronger* axiomatic system, but no system can be proven to be *absolutely* consistent (essentially, the consistency of the given axiomatic system is contingent upon the consistency of the stronger axiomatic system; the system is consistent **iff** the stronger system is consistent).

Is there a way to conclusively prove the **inconsistency** of an axiomatic system, apart from simply chancing upon a contradiction as Russell did?

Side notes:

- I'm assuming the answer is *No*, since if it were possible to
  determine if a system is inconsistent, it would be possible to prove
  if a given statement is decidable in an axiomatic system (this can be done by
  constructing two modified axiomatic systems - one in which the given
  statement is true, and another where it is false - and checking which
  one in inconsistent)
- A related, slightly naive, question: Is it possible to prove the
  inconsistency of a stronger axiomatic system by detecting a contradiction in a weaker axiomatic system?

Comment: What do you mean with "simply chancing upon a contradiction as Russell did?" Russell's discovery of the contradiction implied by Frege's system was a brilliant discovery.

Comment: Deriving a contradiction *is* a proof of inconsistency, "absolute" one. If "stronger axiomatic system" means that it derives all the theorems of "weaker axiomatic system", and the latter derives a contradiction then obviously the former is also inconsistent. If you are asking if there is an algorithm for testing consistency of a given axiomatic system then no, there isn't.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you, this answers the question. Is this a consequence of Gödel's theorems?

Comment: It has more to do with the undecidability of the halting problem, of which Gödel's theorems are also corollaries. But it is not straightforward, see [Decidability of the consistency for complete finitely axiomatized theories?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/419845/152568)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a system is inconsistent (which can be shown by deriving a single contradiction), then of course every system containing this system is inconsistent either.

But a stronger system can be inconsistent even if the weaker system is consistent. Just add a contradictionary axiom as $\ 0=1\ $ to the system.

I do not think that we could show that , for example , PA is inconsistent without detecting a contradiction.